# I have been working on a simple photo editor in Flutter with the features; brightness, contrast and saturation

Tags: python, android, flutter, dart, edit

I am unable to implement the algorithm. I tried doing it in python and succeeded but then how to use the python script in Flutter.

Comment: [This package](https://github.com/srplab/starcore_for_flutter) allows you to call python scripts from Flutter. I wasn't able to get it working with pillow, though.

Answer (score 0):

The best and easiest solution would still be to use official flutter package like this one- https://pub.dev/packages/image_editor_pro. I'd not recommend using external scripts unless flutter equivalent really does not exist.

Comment: I tried to use it pub get command doesn't run for this package ..... otherwise it was the best option